# Using setup functions with tests in a child class

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am writing a test suite for a MATLAB package that handles time series data. The package formats data from various providers with user-written functions that parse a standard input into the correct style and then uses the Datafeed Toolbox to request data. For example, the inputs to the Bloomberg `history` call are different than those of the Haver `fetch` call, but I can use a standard syntax for calls to either one because I parse the inputs within the user-written functions into the correct syntax.

Because each of my user-written functions must behave similarly, when designing the test suite, I wrote `myparentclass.m` (that inherits `matlab.unittest.TestCase`) to test the general behaviors for all them. And further, since some of the user-written functions take special inputs, I wrote a set of child classes, `mychilclass*.m` for each provider that inherits `myparentclass.m` and perform more specific tests. That is, when I executed `runtests('mychildclass1')`, I run both the methods in both `mychildclass1.m` and in `myparentclass.m`. I utilize the `setupOnce` function inside of `mychildclass1.m` to set the user-written function-specific behaviors that are initialized properties on `myparentclass.m`.

The problem that I am running into is that one of my tests, `mychildclass2.m`, requires a directory to be be initialized and for randomized data to be stored there. Currently, the `setupOnce` in `mychildclass2.m` looks like this:

```
testDir = fullfile(pwd(), 'testdir');
if isequal(exist(testDir, 'dir'), 7)
    rmdir(testDir, 's')
end
mkdir(testDir);

startDate = datetime('01-Jan-2018');
endDate = datetime('today');
myDates = transpose(startDate:calmonths(1):endDate);
numDates = length(myDates);
mySeries = randi(10, numDates, 1);
myTable = table(myDates, mySeries);

fname = fullfile(testDir, 'myTable.csv')
writetable(myTable, fname)
```

What I noticed was that contrary to what I thought, the `setupOnce` function is actually executed at the beginning of *every* test called by `mychildclass2.m` (i.e., including those in `myparentclass.m`) instead of just once. I believe this might be the result of the class inheritance or the order in which MATALB executes the functions, but I am not sure. Note that since `mychildclass1.m` does not need this folder with data, I do not want to initialize the folder within `myparentclass.m`.

The question is then, how do I properly write a `setup` function within `mychildclass2.m` so that the data is written only once before all of the tests? The analogous question is how to write the `teardown` function to delete the folder after all of the tests end.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue here is that you are using a TestMethodSetup rather than TestClassSetup. See the Mathworks documentation on this: [Write Setup and Teardown Code Using Classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-setup-and-teardown-code-using-classes.html)

The relevant portion is that

> - TestMethodSetup and TestMethodTeardown methods run before and after each test method.
> - TestClassSetup and TestClassTeardown methods run before and after all test methods in the test case.

---

*Edited to flesh out the answer*

Here would be an example of how you would write this:

```matlab
classdef mychildclass2 < myparentclass

  properties
    fname
  end

  methods (TestClassSetup)
    function createTestTable(testCase)
      startDate = datetime('01-Jan-2018');
      endDate = datetime('today');
      myDates = transpose(startDate:calmonths(1):endDate);
      numDates = length(myDates);
      mySeries = randi(10, numDates, 1);
      myTable = table(myDates, mySeries);

      testCase.fname = tempname;
      writetable(myTable, testCase.fname);
      testCase.addTeardown(@delete, testCase.fname);
    end
  end

  methods (Test)

    function unitTest1(testCase)
      % Do test 1 here
    end

    function unitTest2(testCase)
      % Do test 2 here
    end

  end

end
```

Notice a few things:

1. You do not need to name the functions within the `TestClassSetup` methods block with the keywords `setup` or `setupOnce`. These seem to only be used if you are using the function-based unit testing framework, See [1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-test-using-setup-and-teardown-functions.html)
2. Instead of using the `TestClassTeardown` method I have used the `addTeardown` method. This is what is recommended by the documentation linked above. See [2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.testcase.addteardown.html) for an example.
3. I've removed the creation of the `testdir` directory since it doesn't serve much of a purpose. Instead you can just use the `tempname` function to create a temporary file for this data. If you absolutely need a directory, use the `tempname` function's result as a directory and put your `myTable.csv` in that.

```matlab
testDir = tempname;
mkdir(testDir);
testCase.addTeardown(@rmdir, testCase.fname);
testCase.fname = fullfile(testDir, 'myTable.csv');
writetable(myTable, testCase.fname);
testCase.addTeardown(@delete, testCase.fname);
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Couple quick suggestions:

1) For the benefits of addTeardown, which I also like, read this: https://blogs.mathworks.com/developer/2015/07/27/addteardown/

2) For creating the temporary folder, consider using TemporaryFolderFixture:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.unittest.fixtures.temporaryfolderfixture-class.html